# Builder pattern (java). Why is Builder class public?

Tags: java, design-patterns, private, builder

Why every where I look the inner builder class is public static? Shouldn't it be private static? Maybe I don't see something but I would say it would be better. Could anyone explain it to me?

```
@Getter @AllArgsConstructor @ToString
public class CarDto {

private final String make;
private final int seatCount;
private final String type;
private final CarDto carDto;

public static Builder builder(){
    return new Builder();
}


private static class Builder{
    private String make;
    private int seatCount;
    private String type;
    private CarDto carDto;


    public Builder make(String make){
        this.make = make;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder seatCount(int seatCount){
        this.seatCount = seatCount;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder type(String type){
        this.type = type;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder carDto(CarDto carDto){
        this.carDto = carDto;
        return this;
    }

    public CarDto create(){
        return new CarDto(make, seatCount,type,carDto);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's public so it is accessible to use to make instances of the target class. Why would it be private?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think making it private would be better?

Comment: There's not really much of a difference if you made `Builder` public and called `new CarDto.Builder()...` or have a factory method and called `CarDto.builder()...`

Comment: How would you use the builder if it was private?

Comment: Hello Jakub, welcome to stackoverflow. Please check how builder pattern works. It's basically creating an object without using the constructor from outside of the class. It'll give you a grasp of the topic and you'll understand why that's needed to be public.

Comment: I think the TS concern is about why making inner Builder class public, breaking incapsulation, if we can get it via factory method...

Comment: You can make the builder class non-public when you have a public interface for the access. That’s how [`Stream.builder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#builder--) works.

Comment: As you seem to be using lombok already, why are you manually writing your builder instead of using Lombok's `@Builder`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm pretty sure he has delomboked that 1 annotation and then tweaked it. It would be illogical to ask "why is this class which I declared as public public?"

Comment: Hi to all, thanks for your answers. My question was exactly why there is static method and also the builder class is public.  And yes, this is delomboked @Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Builder` must be public to be accessible from other classes. Try get you builder, calling your static factory method `CarDto.builder()` elsewere - you won't be able to use any of the building methods like `seatCount()`, ..., `create()`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much. I didn't thought about this. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: If you think someone's answer answered your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

A private Builder class would be pretty useless. To start with, you would not even be able to do this:

```
public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
}
```

Because you cannot expose a private class from a public method.

Comment: You *are* able to do that. It will compile. However, for the caller it is fairly useless.

Answer (score 0):

The `Builder` must be available from outside of your `class`. Otherwise how would you be able to use it, to create your objects. You can create a static factory method returning you the `Builder` instance, but the class itself still has to be public.